# Changing ListView selected item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a list view, each item is composed of three elements: picture view and 3 text view, the latter contains the name of a product, product price and quantity, i want  when I click on the item it correspanding  quantity increases by one.
Here's the code:

---

```
    public class BoissonActivity extends Activity {
ListView maListViewPerso;
BaseDeDonne db = new BaseDeDonne(this);
private static String choix="boisson";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.boisson_layout);
maListViewPerso = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewperso);
Log.d("Lire: ", "Lire tous les produits..");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> listItem = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
HashMap<String, Object> map;
listItem.clear();

List<Produit> produit = db.getSelectProduit(choix);

for (Produit cn : produit) {
map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("titre",String.valueOf(cn.getNom()));
map.put("description","Prix:"+cn.getPrix_produit());
map.put("quantite", 0);
String url="/sdcard/Image_Produits/"+cn.getImage_produit()+".jpg";
URL pictureURL = null;
try {
pictureURL = new URL(url);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(url);

map.put("img", bitmap);
listItem.add(map);
String log = "Id: "+cn.getId()+" ,Nom: " + cn.getNom()+ " ,Image: " + cn.getImage_produit() +
" ,Prix: " + cn.getPrix_produit()+" ,Catégorie: " + cn.getCategorie();
Log.d("produits: ", log);
}
SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter (this.getBaseContext(), listItem, R.layout.affichageitem,
new String[] {"img", "titre", "description","quantite"}, new int[] {R.id.img, R.id.titre, R.id.description,R.id.quantite});
mSchedule.setViewBinder(new MyViewBinder());
maListViewPerso.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

i tried this but only the first textview is changed :

```
maListViewPerso.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {   int compteur=0;
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
                TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantite); 

                t.setText(String.valueOf(compteur));
            compteur++;

            }
        });
```

Comment: i want when I click on the item it correspanding quantity(textview) increases by one

Comment: I understand what you want, but what is the question? If you are wanting us to just write the code for you, that will not happen. If you have tried something and it is not working, post your problem and/or error. Then we can assist you in acheiving your goal. But most of us are not going to just turn what you want into code.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onListItemClick..

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

// Your code here to increment the qty   

}
```

**EDIT**

Use the View parameter passed in to access the proper view (i'm taking values from the code you added above, so it doesn't exactly match what I show above).

```
TextView t = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.quantite);  
t.setText(String.valueOf(compteur));
```

Comment: i tried this but only the first textview is changed :

    maListViewPerso.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            { int compteur=0;
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantite); 
                    
                    t.setText(String.valueOf(compteur));
             compteur++;
          
                }
            });

Comment: when i use :TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.quantite); t.setText(String.valueOf(compteur)); only the fist item is modify even when i click on the second item

Comment: You need to select the proper view.  Use the `View v` parameter that is being passed into the onItemClick method.  Try this: `TextView t = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.quantite);`